# Angularjs Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider with using ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the unknown provider error and I am not sure why. My angular controller is not finding the service that I have created. My Service is defined as:

```
var app = angular.module('losApp');

app.service('ClientService', ['$scope','$http','$q',function($scope,$http,$q){ 
    var client = {};//empty oject that will store multiple function

    return client; //return the client object
}]);
```

Also, my controller is defined as:

```
var app = angular.module('losApp');

app.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope', '$modal','ClientService',function($scope, $modal,ClientService){}
```

In my index.html, the scripts tags are declare as follows:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services/ClientService.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DashboardController.js"></script>
```

In app.js, I am using ui-router module to handle routing for the application.

```
var app = angular.module('losApp', ['ngMessages', 'ui.bootstrap',   'angularFileUpload', 'ui.router', 'summernote', 'angucomplete-alt', 'ngCookies']);

   app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,  $interpolateProvider){

   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); //redirects to this page is

     $stateProvider.state('/',{
      url:'/',
       views : {
         // the main template will be placed here (relatively named)
          '':{ 
               templateUrl: '/js/pages/dashboard.html',
               controller: 'DashboardController'
            } 
       }
    });
 });
```

In browser console log and clicked on the angular error message. Additionally, I followed what `angularjs` docs suggested, but still no success.

#### What I am doing wrong and thanks in advance.

Comment: the name of the unknown provider in error will tell you what to look for...what is it?

Comment: the unknown provider is the **ClientService**

Comment: show more of the code for that service.... code shown isn't valid. Oh and you can't keep redeclaring `var app`

Comment: I have updated the Service code and okay thanks for the tip.

Comment: that `var` could be the problem. Try not using it at all `angular.module('losApp').service....`

Comment: Tried it and still getting the same problem.

Comment: try changing the word `service` to `factory` since that is the way you structured the code

Comment: did, but the same problem

Comment: maybe the file is not loading..check network tab in browser dev tools

Comment: the file was found but same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why I was getting unknown provider.It was because I had injected the $scope object into the factory, which is not allowed.

Comment: share the code if possible to keep this answer useful